# UI hangs when multiple httpclient or httpresponse sent

Tags: c#, web-scraping, httpclient, httpresponse

trying to get page source from list of urls. but it hangs the UI. i would prefer httpclient so i can use single instance. please let me know what can i do so it wont hang the ui during the process.

```
    async Task AccessTheWebAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        List<string> urlToSearch = UrlToSearchList();
        IEnumerable<Task<string>> downloadTasksQuery =from url in urlToSearch select ProcessURL2(url, client, ct);
        List<Task<string>> downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToList();

        while (downloadTasks.Count > 0)
        {
            Task<string> firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);
            downloadTasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);
            string length = await firstFinishedTask;
            resultsTextBox.Text += $"\r\nLength of the download:  {length}";
        }
    }

    private List<string> UrlToSearchList()
    {
        var urlToSearchList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in lbURLToSearch.Items)
        {
            urlToSearchList.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        return urlToSearchList;
    }

    async Task<string> ProcessURL2(string url, HttpClient client, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, ct);

        var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return contents;
    }
    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    }

    private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultsTextBox.Clear();
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            await AccessTheWebAsync(cts.Token);
            resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads complete.";
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads canceled.\r\n";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads failed.\r\n";
        }

        cts = null;
    }
```

i also tried various async methods. still same result, it hangs. below is one of the async method i tried.

```
    private async void TsbtnStartURLScraper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lbURLToSearch.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            txtScrapeURL.Text = lbURLToSearch.Items[i].ToString();
            string urlAddress = lbURLToSearch.Items[i].ToString();
            var returnedresult = await DownloadStringV1(urlAddress);
            resultsTextBox.Text += returnedresult;
        }

    }
    public async Task<String> DownloadStringV1(String url)
    {
        // good code
        var request = await reusableHTTPClient.GetAsync(url);
        var download = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return download;
    }
```

NOTE: what i am trying to do is, loop through a list of url and get page source from them. but when i am doing this it is freezing the form.

Comment: use async method

Comment: tried, doesnt help. same outcome, still freezes.

Comment: Could you trim the code down into a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: How many URLs are you requesting? Async or not, you can still overwhelm the application. If this is because you have too many in flight calls you should throttle them to a certain amount at a time.

Comment: @Quelklef - as you can see this is my first post, so i tried my best. i posted the exact code i am using.

Comment: @Crowcoder - not sure of the exact amount, it can vary from 5 to 500. if there is a better way to do it, please suggest me.

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your issue, but the HttpClient should be made static. It's intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application. This is pretty well documented. https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/